# Remove Delay for android textPassword

Tags: android, passwords, android-edittext

While enterting password inside EditText view, Characters are being shown and after some delay it is shown as DOT, i want to remove this delay. It should be displayed directly as DOT.

How do i do this on Android?

Comment: @Lipis Even while entering the password no body should be able to see that what characters i am entering. :)

Comment: Not even you...! :) People do mistakes with our giant fingers.. and it's pretty annoying when you entering your password for the 5th time and it still says wrong password.. :)

Comment: @Lipis Its pretty dangerous that even if i am entering password person beside me is able to see all the characters,:)

Comment: How are you going to hide your fingers from prying eyes too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Hide password **forcefully**,

> android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.TEXT_SHOW_PASSWORD,
>    0);

**Note** : It will not show any characters, Directly DOTs will be displayed without any delay inside your View having **android:password** attribute set to **true**

Comment: Compiles but probably needs permission. Also I need something local to one view.

Answer (score 1):

This is a user setting within Android, I do not believe that it is controllable from code. It is designed to aid the user in entering the correct password.

--Edit--
Further to the question askers comment, the setting can be found in:

Settings > Security > Make passwords visible

The above relates to Android ICS, the setting should be similar in previous versions.

Comment: User setting within Android where can i configure that?

Comment: It is in the security section of the settings menu (in ICS at least) there is the option to "Make passwords visible".

Comment: it works after i uncheck make password visible but can't i do this programatically?

Comment: I found the way to do it programatically. :)

Comment: @user370305 I have shared the solution as an answer to this question, which really works like an angel :)

Answer (score 0):

Use code from AOSP *PasswordTransformationMethod.java* and modify it to suit your needs. Create new class *MyPasswordTransformationMethod* from it and modify the *Visible* class inside it. 
It would also need to change rest of the code because it accesses some private properties, but they are mostly constants so it is quite easy.

```
private static class Visible
extends Handler
implements UpdateLayout, Runnable
{
    public Visible(Spannable sp, MyPasswordTransformationMethod ptm) {
        mText = sp;
        mTransformer = ptm;
        //postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 1500); 
        //replaced with following line
        postAtFrontOfQueue(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        mText.removeSpan(this);
    }

    private Spannable mText;
    private MyPasswordTransformationMethod mTransformer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is very old, but here is a helpful tip! (That also would work)

If you move the focus from the current EditText to the next it will skip the delay, so if you're creating a PIN screen, then you just need to immediately move focus onto the next "pin" and it will skip the delay and immediately show the asterisk.

You might also be able to set a rootView or container as focusable and give focus to that if you only have 1 EditText.