# how to retain the behaviour of password field in android while customizing the same

Tags: android, passwords, default, behavior

I have a edit text which accepts "*" as input for password. I did the same using a class which extends PasswordTransformationMethod

If I use the above change, it reflects in the password edittext. But the default behaviour of password field is gone.

**I mean the character pressed displays for a fraction of sec and then changes to "DOT" in case of default android password**

**But in case of asterisk, it directly comes as asterisk. Please let me know how can I achieve the same?**

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152379/remove-delay-for-android-textpassword

Comment: It is the reverse of what i want? I want the characters to be displayed for a fraction of sec before changing it to "*"